# set dropdownlist datasource and values at runtime using C#

Tags: c#, dropdown

If setting a DropDownList's `DataSourceID` to a SqlDataSource at runtime depending on certain conditions, how do I set what field from the SqlDataSource to show and what to set as its value?
Currently I have the code below:

```
protected void chkBondedStock_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkBondedStock.Checked)
    {
        ddlProject.DataSourceID = "SqlBond_Y";
        ddlProject.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        ddlProject.DataSourceID = "SqlBond_N";
        ddlProject.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean without refreshing the page?

Comment: yes, I'll probably put it inside an update panel, but just unsure how to set the value and the visible text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're using the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList` control. If so, you should use:

```
ddlProject.DataValueField = "ValueField";
ddlProject.DataTextField = "TextField";
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield(v=vs.110).aspx